# Replace text that shows up in an boolean attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am developing a project in asp.net MVC.
In this project, I use some boolean data types that are displayed on the screen, but they appear as true/false according to whether the property is "selected" or not on the screen.

How can I change the label from true/false to yes/no?

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide some example code that you've already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following should help you convert bool to Yes/No strings.

```
string.Format("{0:Yes;0;No}", value.GetHashCode());
```

Another option would be to use a simple condition

```
result = value ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: Or just `value ? "Yes" : "No"`

Comment: @stuartd added that. For some unknown reason, i had affinity towards stringformat approach, that's why added that first.

Comment: I didn't know that `true.GetHashCode()` is 1, I can think of a few times that would have been useful, so thanks for that :)

Comment: The code for [`Boolean.GetHashCode()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,80) is just `value ? 1 : 0`, so you're just adding more condition evaluations by using it. I don't see the point of using it. (you'd never notice a difference in speed, it's just more confusing and no benefit)

Comment: @GabrielLuci thanks for bringing that up. Yes you are right.Readability is affected, while the internal code is same as the second option.

Answer (score 1):

you are not provide code, So I am giving you a simple example.

**Model**

```
public class testMdl
{
   public boolean IsActive
   {get;set;}
}
```

Now, you set IsActive=false in your controller and pass it in razor .cshtml page.

**Razor .cshtml code**

```
@{ string isActive= @Model.IsActive == true ? "Yes" : "No" ; }

<span>Account Status: @isActive</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must have both the `bool` and `string` values, you could use a class for this purpose.

A public `bool` property that can be `get` and `set`, and a `string` that can only do `get` based on the `bool` value.

```
public class BoolYesNo
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public string YesNo { get { return Value ? "Yes" : "No"; } }
}

var val = new BoolYesNo() { Value = true };
Console.WriteLine(val.Value);
Console.WriteLine(val.YesNo);
```

Output

> True
>
> Yes